# Eclipse: Could not find Java 2 Runtime Environment

Tags: java, eclipse, runtime-environment

I just installed Eclipse 3.5. Before I could install the Android Plugin I needed to install a Java jdk, which I did. After restart Im not able to start Eclipse anymore, because I receive the following error:

> Error: could not finde Java 2 Runtime
>   Environment

The weired thing is, that now I cant even open my other Eclipse Installations, that I use for PHP Programming. Any suggestions?

**Update:**

This is my eclipse.ini:

> ```
> -startup
> plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.201.R35x_v20090715.jar
> --launcher.library
> plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.0.200.v20090519
> -showsplash
> org.eclipse.platform
> --launcher.XXMaxPermSize
> 256m
> -vmargs
> -Xms40m
> -Xmx256m
> ```

Comment: check your eclipse.ini file , there should be misconfiguration

Comment: You might need to set your environment's PATH to include the 'bin' directory of your JDK install.

Comment: have you checked eclipse.ini ?

Answer (score 6):

You can explicitely tell your eclipse session which jdk/jre you want it to start with adding the following in your eclipse.ini:

> -vm
>   c:/your/jre/bin/javaw.exe

For more info on how to startup your eclipse refer [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse%3F)

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem, with exception that Java was installed successfully.
Once I added c:/my-path-to-java/jre/bin to PATH (system environment variable), Eclipse started successfully.

Comment: I like this better than changing the eclipse.ini file

Answer (score 3):

Change the `PATH` environment variable from something like

```
...;%SystemRoot%\System32;...;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin;...
```

to something like

```
...;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin;...;%SystemRoot%\System32;...
```

Answer (score 2):

Check your path variable from Computer's System Properties Environment Variables JAVA_HOME to ocorrect path to your jdk installation

Comment: I created the variable JAVA_HOME with the value "C:\Programme\java\jdk1.6.0_23" but it didnt work. Do I have to reference a specific file within that folder?

Comment: @paskster Maybe adding JAVA_HOME wants to restarting computer. Otherwise I think installing JDK again will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Wonder if the Java install might be corrupt. Can you run the following on the Run prompt and paste what you get in code tags:

```
dir /d /s "%JAVA_HOME%" > "%HOMEPATH%\java2.txt" && notepad "%HOMEPATH%\java2.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense that your PHP eclipse won't start either.  Eclipse runs on java itself.  Probably it cannot find the JRE.

so I see two possibilities:

- The JRE is corrupt and you should reinstall it
- Eclipse is getting confused by the 2 jre (unlikely to me) and you need to point it to the right one (as suggested by Dimistrisli).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Eclipse (3.7) worked just fine for a while with JDK 6, and then I installed JRE 5 (please don't ask me why)

[This eclipse wiki page](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse?), which seems up to date, states that:

> If a JVM is installed in the eclipse/jre directory, Eclipse will use
>   it; otherwise the launcher will consult the eclipse.ini file and the
>   system path variable. Eclipse DOES NOT consult the JAVA_HOME
>   environment variable

And indeed, I did not change JAVA_HOME so that couldn't be it.
However, at the bottom of the same wiki page, someone added:

> A comment on the JVM search order (on Windows) - My testing (Windows
>   7, Eclipse 3.4.1) shows that Eclipse also looks for a JVM in the
>   registry, in my case HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft\Java Runtime
>   Environment

So I found the mentioned registry entry, which now had the value of "1.5" and changed it to "1.6", then restarted my PC (windows 7), and voila - Eclipse went back alive.

I agree that adding "-vm" might fix this, although it didn't seem to work for me (maybe I didn't add it in the right place/format). But IMO, the registry fix was the better one in my case. After restarting my computer and seeing Eclipse was back to normal, I uninstalled JRE 5 (through "Add or remove programs") just to tie up loose ends.

Answer (score 1):

In my case installing the most recent JRE worked well: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I recently installed JDK 7 Update 9. My eclipse did not open and when I run "java -version" from CMD, it did not work either.
I had PATH variable set to the correct bin directory.

Anyways, eventually when I set JAVA_HOME to the new installation directory, eclipse started fine. Not sure what is the problem with JDK 7 Update 9.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure everything is setup correctly under "installed JREs" under the Eclipse preferences.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution that worked for me, since other resolution  required admin privilege is executing the below command from command prompt

eclipse -vm C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_72\bin\javaw

Also, to make the eclipse shortcut work by editing the shortcut.Append -vm C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_72\bin\javaw in the target section